# How should I pass a custom logger from a file to multiple modules and while maintaining sub-module granularity?

Tags: python, logging

I have a logging class that describes a base logger.

```
class logger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.filelocation = 'log/util.log'
        self.loggers = {}
    def init_logger(self,name="util",):
        if self.loggers.get(name):
            return self.loggers.get(name)
        else:
            module_logger = logging.getLogger(name)
            module_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
            module_logger.propagate = False
            # create file handler which logs even debug messages
            fh = logging.FileHandler(self.filelocation)
            fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

            # create console handler with a higher log level
            ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
            ch.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

        # create formatter and add it to the handlers
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(module)s : %(levelname)s : %(asctime)s : %(name)s : %(message)s')

        fh.setFormatter(formatter)
        ch.setFormatter(formatter)
        # add the handlers to the logger
        module_logger.addHandler(fh)
        module_logger.addHandler(ch)
        self.loggers[name] = module_logger
        return module_logger
```

Now I have multiple modules referencing the above said logger. For ex

```
# mod1.py
logsession = logger().init_logger(name = "athena_s3")
dictsession = logger().init_logger(name = "dictinfo")
class mod1_class(): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = etc
    def build_session(self):
        """

        Build a session using the athena client

        Input: None

        Return: Active session

        """
        if not self._session:
            try:
                self._session = Session(aws_access_key_id = self._aws_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key = self._aws_secret_access_key)
                logsession.info("Built new athena session")
```

Similarly I have another module that could reference the code from the above mod1.py. Now consider a `test.py` file that imports this `mod1.py`.

```
from mod1 import mod1_class
session = mod1_class().build_session()

### Do STUFF
```

How can I pass the logger from multiple `test.py` to `mod1.py` such that it maintains the same logger ? 
So for example:

logs could be

```
test : INFO : time : athena_s3 : message
test : INFO : time : athena_s3 : athena_util : message
test2: INFO : time : athena_s2 : message
```

Comment: `logging.getLogger(name)` this will return the same logging object in each class, just use a consistent `name`.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more ?

Comment: `logging.getLogger(...)` is basically a way to get existing logger objects from a global level. So dont pass the logger, just you `getLogger` to in essence import it. `logging.getLogger('athena_s3')`

Comment: but that would limit me to Athena_s3 logger. say I have another module that imports this, how can I pass in the logger from there ?

Comment: If the logger name is dynamic then I am not sure. You are better off changing the default logger and just using that